# Graphs all appear on same plot in Jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

I want to display a a series of graphs using a loop on one plot in a Jupyter cell, and then in another cell to display another plot.
I plot this curves on the first plot using a loop:

```
def plotTrajectory(launchAngle):
    [yRange, xRange] = setTrajectory(launchAngle)
    plt.plot(yRange, xRange, label=launchAngle)
    plt.ylabel('Vertical distance (m)')
    plt.xlabel('Horiontal distance (m)')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.79, 1), title='Launch angle', loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)

for i in launchAngles:
    plotTrajectory(i)
```

and then try to plot another curve in a separate cell:

```
plt.plot(angleRange90, heights, label='Height')
plt.show()
```

and both appear on the same plot. Do I need plt.close() or plt.clf()? I'm sure this is simple and is a misunderstanding I have about how matplotlib works, but I can find nothing online regarding this specific case.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`plt.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html):

```
def plotTrajectory(launchAngle):
    [yRange, xRange] = setTrajectory(launchAngle)
    plt.plot(yRange, xRange, label=launchAngle)
    plt.ylabel('Vertical distance (m)')
    plt.xlabel('Horiontal distance (m)')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.79, 1), title='Launch angle', loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)


for i in launchAngles:
    plotTrajectory(i)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(angleRange90, heights, label='Height')
plt.show()
```